# How to Connect Tkinter Application with Django User Model?

Tags: python, django, tkinter

I got stuck in one Place. I have a Tkinter Application and Web Application on Django. I have a login system in both Application. Rather making two distinct User Model, I want to linked My Tkinter Desktop Application with Django user Model so that I can synchronized the User data in both Application but the problem is when I am checking the password in my tkinter Application it is checking it as a plain text but the password in django User Model cannot be decrypt. So, Is there any way that I can synchronized my Desktop Application (Tkinter) and Web Application (Django) with one User Model (Django)?

Comment: Use the same encryption function of Django to encrypt the password before doing the authentication.

Comment: And What about decryption? The problem is tkinter application is checking password as a plain text.

Comment: What I mean is that you use the Django encryption to encrypt the password in your tkinter application and check the encrypted password with the one stored in the database.

Comment: how do i get the Django encryption method? can show us a demonstration example, please?

Answer (score 0):

How to Connect Tkinter Application with Django User Model?-
Step number0: Put in same directory as django application
Step number1: Create a basic tkinter app
Step number2: import the user models

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.